# How can I make a heatmap from a repetitive dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I've got a df that has three columns, one of them has a repetitive pattern, the df looks like this

```
>>> df
        date        hour        value      
   0  01/01/2022     1        0.267648 
   1  01/01/2022     2        1.564420  
   2  01/01/2022    ...       0.702019 
   3  01/01/2022     24       1.504663  
   4  01/02/2022     1        0.309097 
   5  01/02/2022     2        0.309097 
   6  01/02/2022    ...       0.309097 
   7  01/02/2022     24       0.309097 
>>>
```

I want to make a heatmap with this, the x-axis would be the month, the y axis the hour of the day and the value would be the median of all the values in that specific hour from everyday in the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['month'] = df.date.dt.month

pivot = df.pivot_table(columns='month', index='hour', values='value', aggfunc='median')

sns.heatmap(pivot.sort_index(ascending=False))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

- [Seaborn Heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

Comment: In testing I appear to have made 24 into 0, so yours will looks slightly different.